# How to extract URL from an HTML

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I'm a newbie in web scraping. I do as below

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("http://chgk.tvigra.ru/letopis/?2016/2016_spr#27mar")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
res = soup.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile("r'\b?20\b'")})
print (res)
```

and get

```
[]
```

My goal is this fragment

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
cont = new Array();
count = new Array();
for (i=1979; i <=2015; i++){count[i]=0};
cont[1979] =    "<li><a href='?1979_1#24jan'>24 января</a>" +
```

..............

```
cont[2016] =    "<li><a href='?2016/2016_spr#cur'>Весенняя серия</a>" +
        "<li><a href='?2016/2016_sum#cur'>Летняя серия</a>" +
        "<li><a href='?2016/2016_aut#cur'>Осенняя серия</a>" +
        "<li><a href='?2016/2016_win#cur'>Зимняя серия</a>";
```

And i try to get the result like this

```
'?2016/2016_spr#cur' 
'?2016/2016_sum#cur'
'?2016/2016_aut#cur'
'?2016/2016_win#cur'
```

From 2000 to this moment (so '20' in `"r'\b?20\b'"` is for this reason). Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminaries:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> page = requests.get('http://chgk.tvigra.ru/letopis/?2016/2016_spr#27mar').content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

Having done this it might seem that the most straightforward way of identifying the `script` element might be to use this:

```
>>> scripts = soup.findAll('script', text=bs4.re.compile('cont = new Array();'))
```

However, `scripts` proves to be an empty list. (I don't know why.)

The basic approach works, if I choose a different target within the script but it would appear the it's unsafe to depend on the exact formatting of the content of Javascript script element.

```
>>> scripts = soup.find_all(string=bs4.re.compile('i=1979'))
>>> len(scripts)
1
```

Still, this might be good enough for you. Please just notice that the script has the `change` function at the end to be discarded.

A safer approach might be to look for the containing `table` element, then the second `td` element within that and finally the `script` within that.

```
>>> table = soup.find_all('table', class_='common_table')
>>> tds = table[0].findAll('td')[1]
>>> script = tds.find('script')
```

Again, you will need to discard function `change`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get('attribute')` and then filter the results if needed:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://chgk.tvigra.ru/letopis/?2016/2016_spr#27mar")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
res = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
print (res)
```

Comment: I did like this but i got for ample for `2000` just '?2000', not ?`2000_exp#10sep` as i want